# passing data between children using XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xlpagertabstrip

am using https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip and i have 3 children ... i want to pass value from child to child ..

am able to pass value from parent to first child like this:

```
    let parentVC = self.parent as! ParentViewController
    mobile = parentVC.mobile
```

but now i want to pass it from child 1 to child 2 .. tried the above but i got that **mobile is nil**

[image]

and mobile in the parentview is declared like this:

```
    var mobile = ""
```

how can i pass data between children?

```
       override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cominfo")
    let child2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "comedu")
    let child3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "comcv")        
    return [child1,child2,child3]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can pass data to parent first then you can access all child from parent.

Comment: i got nil tried this ...

Comment: @DharmeshKheni can you please show how you declared the variable mobile in your parentViewController?

Comment: Update your post and show how you tried?

Comment: @Shezad This is not my question. :)

Comment: @Shezad please check my updated post

Comment: @DharmeshKheni please check my updated post

Comment: @DharmeshKheni you can't get data from parent VC using this method, you can only pass data to child VC using this method, if you want to get data use Delegate method. or please explain the scenario.

Comment: @Shezad i want to get mobile from the parent vc .. am able to do this using what am doing in the first child .. but in the second child am getting the error ..

Comment: @Shezad This is not my post please stop tagging me.

Comment: @Lama if you want to get from parent VC, you could just pass the value while you push VC from parent VC to child VC

Comment: @Shezad how to do this?

Comment: @Lama can you just show the code which you used to push to child VC

Comment: @Shezad check updates please

Comment: @Lama to which childVC you need to pass data? and to which variabale??

Comment: @Shezad all of them .. mobile

Comment: @Lama so you need to pass value to variable mobile in child VC's??

Comment: @Shezad yes exactly i want to pass mobile from parent to children's mobile

Comment: @Lama just try the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    let child1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cominfo") as! yourChildClassname
    child1.mobile = self.mobile
    let child2 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "comedu")as! yourChildClassname
    child2.mobile = self.mobile
    let child3 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "comcv")  as! yourChildClassname
    child3.mobile = self.mobile       
return [child1,child2,child3]
 }
```

Comment: already tried this and didn't work .. can you check last screenshot in my post please

Comment: @Lama so in child VC you haven't declared a variable named mobile?

Comment: @Lama so please copy that exact variable and paste it after Child1.

Comment: it is the same T_T

Comment: Please add your VC class after that

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: oh ok .. just a minute

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue until I found simple solution:
I use singleton design pattern here by take instance from super class
and set shared property over there and then it shared over all Childs